In django template cannot get data from values_list() for select options dropdown
Im django noob here so I would like to get your support. Thank you so much in advanced.
model.py
class Province(models.Model):     
        province_name = models.CharField() 

class Employee(models.Model):    
        first_name = models.CharField()    
        province = models.ForeignKey(Province, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

filters.py (django-filters)
from django_filters import FilterSet, filters
    from .models import (
        Employee,
        Province,
    )

    class EmployeeFilter(FilterSet):
        province_name_multi_select = (
            filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
                field_name="province_id",
                queryset=Province.objects.values_list("id", "province_name"),  
            )
        )

        class Meta:
            model = Employee
            fields = [
                "id",
                "first_name",
                "province",
            ]

views.py
class EmployeeListView(FilterView):
        model = Employee
        queryset = Employee.objects.select_related(
            "province",
        )
        form_class = EmployeeForm
        strict = False
        context_object_name = "employees_list"
        filterset_class = EmployeeFilter

employee_filter.html
<select class="form-select" name="province_name_multi_select" id="multiple-select-field" multiple\>  
    {% for element in filter.form.province_name_multi_select %}
    {{ element.tag }} \<= **Problem happened here**
    {% endfor %}
    </select\>

problem
Above {{ element.tag }} produced <option value="[1], 'abc province']" </option\>
But what I want it to produce is, you can guess that <option value="1" </option\>
convert output of values_list (tuple?) to list to render in django html template's select dropdown

The desired result you want can't be achieved with the usage of value_list() query method because it only returns tuples, use all() query instead to better extract the individual values of the dropdown options. On the template, you can now loop through the Province objects filter. Your code snippet modification will look like this below when we make those changes.
# filters.py
class EmployeeFilter(FilterSet):
    province_name_multi_select = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        field_name="province",
        queryset=Province.objects.all(), # not value_list()
        to_field_name="id"
    )
class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ["id", "first_name", "province"]
#other fields if any :-)

<!--templates.html-->
<select class="form-select" name="province_name_multi_select" id="multiple-select-field" multiple>
    {% for element in filter.form.province_name_multi_select.field.queryset %}
        <option value="{{ element.id }}">{{ element.province_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>



I’m sad because I already used all() like you mentioned but it’s query time in Django debug toolbar took longer than values_list. That why now I am trying to find a way to use values_list. Is it really no way to use values_list in this scenario? Thanks anyway

I am glad that the answer I gave returned the expected data you want in your dropdown option menu. There are many things you can do on django queryset-api to optimize the lag time, thus enhancing performance if the retrieved data is quite large. For example, you can use slicing to reduce the number of data retrieved (.all()[:100] for e.g), you can use prefetched, .value() which returns a dict or implement catching via the api call. I think with these examples, you can optimize your api query call. PS: Don't forget to thick the answer correct because it answered your initial question, mate.

Thanks.Im really sorry could you show me which ink or button I will click or press to thick your answer correct? Then surely I will do that. Thanks again! I looked elsewjere but not found it.

Sure, mate. Where my answer I gave, on the first sentence i made, you will see an up-arrow like button, just click on it and that's it.

Oh I see. I did not know its a button. I clicked it. Nice week ahead!

I appreciate your honesty, mate. However, is kinda complex because it is still not marked as answered question. Kindly google on how to tick answer of already answered question on stackoverflpw perha0s it miggt be of help. Thank you
